# I am not able to select a particular row in listview

Tags: android, listview

Hello all
I created a custom listview through my custom adapter..

```
    CustomAdapter adapter  = new CustomAdapter(MainPage.this, dbHelper, imgId, title);
                    adapter.setList(list1);
                    list1.setAdapter(adapter);


                    list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.i("hello",arg2+"item clicked ....");
                            Toast.makeText(MainPage.this, "Kindly enter search parameter!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
--
```

Now i am not able to select any item. I dont know why.....

Comment: is your customadapter extending baseadapter?

Comment: Yes it is extending baseadapter... Everything else is working f9 only just i am not able to get an event on onItemclicklistener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the inflated view "Clickable" and "able to listen to click events" in your adapter class getView() method.

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
convertView.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: Hello jkhou... i figured out wot was the problem... in my listview i used custom buttons and i set their setfocusable property to false.due to which the listview onitemclicklistener lost its focus...Thanks for the reply :)